# Debugging mixed Python C++ in VS Code. Can't enter sudo password

Tags: python, c, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

Following the instructions in:
https://nadiah.org/2020/03/01/example-debug-mixed-python-c-in-visual-studio-code/

I ran into a strange error. In step five it reads:

*In the terminal, VS Code will tell you that superuser access is required to attach to a process. Type in Y and enter the root password.*

However I can't type 'Y' since an extra line is added when I am asked if I want to continue as a super user. See image:

[image: source /.../venv/bin/activate appears in an unexpected place]

My launch.json is:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Attach",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/venv/bin/python", /* My virtual env */
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to launch VS Code as a super user to no avail. Adding sudo to 'MIMode' is not valid either.

I tried the solutions proposed in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4988 to no avail either.

Help is very much appreciated !

Comment: reference for those who are interested in how you can remove the super-user (ptrace) limitation:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug#_debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much searching and brain storming I am finally able to debug both Python and CPP code via VS Code. Sequence of steps are as follows:

1. Install Python C++ Debugger" extension [[link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjamin-simmonds.pythoncpp-debug)]. This extension will remove the pain to manually enter the C++ process id.
2. Here is my "launch.json" file for reference on how to use this new extension:

   {

   ```
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Python C++ Debug",
           "type": "pythoncpp",
           "request": "launch",
           "pythonLaunchName": "Python: Current File",
           "cppConfig": "default (gdb) Attach"
       },
       {
           "name": "Python: Current File",
           "type": "python",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "/home/agaurav/main.py",
           "console": "integratedTerminal",
           "env": {
               "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/path/to/lib1:/path/to/lib2"
           },
           "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
       }
   ]
   ```

   }
3. Finally, set ptrace_scope to 0 so that we allow one process to examine and modify another process. Do this by running this command:

> echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope

And done. Now you can set breakpoint at both Python and Cpp

Comment: I am trying to do the same but in a container... During debugging, the terminal of CPPtools is open but nothing shown and the breakpoint in my CPP doesn't have any effect. Is there additional configurations that needs to be done for debugging inside the container? I have my Dockerfile with all packages needed instalked and runArgs in devcontainer.json setup to debug C++ (as explained in the same default file). What am I missing here???

Comment: I am trying to do the same but in a container... During debugging, the terminal of CPPtools is open but nothing shown and the breakpoint in my CPP doesn't have any effect. Is there additional configurations that needs to be done for debugging inside the container? I have my Dockerfile with all packages needed instalked and runArgs in devcontainer.json setup to debug C++ (as explained in the same default file). What am I missing here???

Comment: echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope this is the single most important line, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using VSCode version 1.42.1. I don't know if other version work too. I hope this helps, but if you have a better solution using the latest version, please let us know by posting your answer. I reported this issue as a bug.

**UPDATE:**
This bug was solved in VSCode version 1.52.1.

Happy coding !